# Is there a way to package a Shoes Ruby App into an APK?

Tags: ruby, package, apk, shoes, shoes-4

I am aware that I can package a Shoes Ruby app into a **dmg**, **exe**, and other Linux formats, but can I do an APK? I'm hoping to run a Shoes app on my Samsung Galaxy. Is there some gem or some long process to achieve this? Any method will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely the answer is no and even if someone somehow built a way it probably won't be something you will want to use. GUI programming between desktop and mobile is very different and you will usually have to use different tools for both. The best you will get is writing a GUI using HTML/CSS/JS and using tools to get those running on mobile and desktop.